# How to search with Spring JPA Repository for a string with apostrophe

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have 
- User model with id, name, email and timestamps attributes
- UserRepository
- Postgres database with users table with two rows (Joseph, O'Reilly)

When I perform

- User user = userRepository.findFirstByName("O'Reilly");
  I don't get the user, user is null
- User user = userRepository.findFirstByName("Joseph");
  I get the user, user is not null

What should I do to get the result with a string search like "O'Reilly"

(I use Spring Framework 1.5.6.RELEASE)

Comment: Did you try escaping the apostrophe? User user = userRepository.findFirstByName("O\'Reilly"); You can also try in SQL way: User user = userRepository.findFirstByName("O''Reilly");

Answer (score 0):

You can use (native) query in that case

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM table_name "
                                 + "WHERE col_name = :name collate utf8_bin")
public List<EntityName> find(@Param("name") String name);
```